# Converting dictionary file to separate txt files

Tags: conversion, dictionary, plaintext

I have data in .dict and .lsd (abby lingvo) dictionary files.
I need to convert either of them to set of .txt files.
Each article shoud be in separate plain utf8 text file.
Is there some utility for that?

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no ready-made utility solution. At least superuser.com visitors and  I can't find it.

There is [Linguae application](http://stalikez.info/linguae/), that can convert .dict (and others) dictionaries into some other formats. Binary and [XDXF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDXF) are among them. XDXF is XML bases, so it must be a lot easyer to work with it. Most probably coding is required.